# Unable to set image Button- swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, uiimage

I have a core data app(like a Diary) in which I prompt user to pick an image from Camera or Photo Library and set it to ImageData and then to the button's image. This part works but if user doesnt choose image and just write the text and press Done. It gives me "unexpectedly found nil" error. I have ann image named "icn_noimage" so if user hasnt selected any image, this image will be set to button. I tried to do it this way:
Here, imageData, body, date are attributes of core data.

```
 var pickedImage: UIImage! {
    didSet {
        if (pickedImage == nil) {
            self.imageButton?.setImage(UIImage(named: "icn_noimage"), forState: .Normal)
        } else {
            self.imageButton?.setImage(pickedImage, forState: .Normal)
        }
    }
}

 func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    let image: UIImage! = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.pickedImage = image

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

  func insertDiaryEntry() {
    let coreDataStack: CoreDataStack = CoreDataStack.defaultStack
    let entry: DiaryEntry = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("DiaryEntry", inManagedObjectContext: coreDataStack.managedObjectContext) as! DiaryEntry
    entry.body = self.textView.text
    entry.date = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
    entry.mood = self.pickedMood!.rawValue

    entry.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.pickedImage, 0.75)

    entry.location = self.location as String
    coreDataStack.saveContext()

}
```

In case, I have been unable to explain my question, please ask the details.
Appreciate your help.....

Comment: On which line of code app is crashing ?

Comment: @technerd On this line: entry.imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.pickedImage, 0.75)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure `"icn_noimage"` image available in your bundle.

And still mark `imageData` as Optional in `DiaryEntry` class.

Use imageData with Optional(?) , `imageData?`.

This will accept nil value of image Data in case image not available.

If it is already optional then use conditional Un-wrapping.

```
if let image = self.pickedImage
{
   let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.75)
   entry.imageData = imageData
}
```

Comment: image is available and imageData is optional with '?'